# How to start yarn in sudo root?

Tags: bash, terminal, hadoop-yarn, root, sudo

I have a problem on my project, i need to be in super user for start my backend part of my project. Instead of use the command sudo npm start, my boss want me to use yarn but when I try sudo yarn dev (dev is a script that correspond to nest start --watch) I have this error: 00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dev'

Anyone have a solution to this ?

I tried to give permissions to the .yarn file on ~./yarn with a chown command

Comment: "No such file or directory: 'dev'" means that you are missing your "dev" script.

Comment: Yes I known that, but it isn't normal because "yarn dev" is working

Comment: How about giving the full path to "dev": `sudo yarn $PWD/dev`.

Comment: It is the same. Maybe this problem come from my bashrc/zshrc ?